# Why is my application pool having memory usage spikes?

Tags: asp.net, iis, memory, memory-management

I hosted my application in production. Within 5 to 6 hours the application pool spikes and uses more memory?

What application objects or system objects are stored in the application pool?

Answer (score 2):

An application pool is a worker process spawned by IIS to host one or more applications. The memory raise behavior you are observing could be due to various reasons such as objects that hold unmanaged resources not being disposed properly, storing large objects in the [application state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.aspx), ... You could use a [profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm) to find the exact cause.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for memory leaks, try downloading the trial version of [MemProfiler](http://memprofiler.com/) (or one of the other products available).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers by [Mitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175240/app-pool-spikes-more-memory/2175251#2175251) and [Darin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175240/app-pool-spikes-more-memory/2175255#2175255), I'd also recommend taking a look at [Tess Ferrandez's excellent blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/default.aspx) which deals with issues such as memory/use leaks:

> [.NET Debugging Demos Lab 3: Memory](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2008/02/15/net-debugging-demos-lab-3-memory.aspx)
>   [.NET Debugging Demos Lab 6: Memory Leak](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2008/03/17/net-debugging-demos-lab-6-memory-leak.aspx)
>   [.NET Debugging Demos Lab 7: Memory Leak](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2008/03/25/net-debugging-demos-lab-7-memory-leak.aspx)